# Cloud function query returning null even though it should return a value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the structure of the database,

```
Content {
   "randomID" {
      "randomID2" {
         "text": "Hello World"
             }
      }
}
```

I'm trying to do a query in cloud functions, to check if text is equalTo a specific value but it always returns null

```
admin.database().ref('Content').orderByChild('text').equalTo("someText").once('value').then(snapshot => {

     console.log(snapshot.val()); -> this returns null

})
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is that I have two random ID's there, also wildcards don't work for .once('value') like they do for onUpdate I believe. Or I'm doing something wrong as I'm quite new to Javascript.

Comment: why do u have two random ids?

Comment: @peterhaddad randomID is the userID, inside userID, I have all the random2 ids which point to a specific conversation.

Comment: Firebase Database query check the **direct child nodes** of the location you run them against. So in your case it checks whether `/Content/randomID` has a property `text` with value `sometext`. In the data you shared it doesn't have that, so nothing is returned. Firebase queries do not test against nested child nodes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so I should fetch without OrderByChild first, then do another fetch .ref('Content/' + snapshot.val()).once('value'), won't this cause a lot of data usage? Because in my app, "Content" has a lot of nodes.

Comment: You'll need to restructure (or add an additional structure) to allow the use-case you want. Downloading too much data is a bad idea, so add a structure that allows the query. The answer I linked has an example of that.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
admin.database().ref('Content').orderByChild('text')
```

should be changed to

```
admin.database().ref('Content/{randomID}/{randomID2}').orderByChild('text')
```

you can't skip the ids in the reference

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. It still returns null, I'm 100% sure that equalTo("some text") should return a value because I intentionally did so but it doesn't :/

Comment: does it return a value without the equalTo?

Comment: No it still returns null

Comment: did u update the reference to include the ids as in the answer?

Comment: Yes, still returns null, not really sure why.

Comment: Ok, u can back trace the nodes start at Content -> Content/{rId} and check if the return values and try without the orderByChild plus check if the text is indexed

Comment: still returning null and yes "text" is indexed. I'm not sure if admin.database().ref() supports wildcards

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference

Comment: Go back to the root and start from there admin.database().ref(); with no order or equal queries and start adding or make multiple versions and see which returns a value